# ES6 Map type alias doesn't work

Tags: typescript, typescript1.8

I need to collect some errors for multiple fields, so the structure in general looks like:

```
{
  name: { 
    errors: ['error one', 'error two']
  },
  age: {
    errors: ['error three', 'error four']
  }
}
```

What I wanted to do was to type things in Typescript, so I did the following:

```
interface FieldErrors {
  errors: string[]
}

type ErrorsBag = Map<string, FieldErrors>;
```

Sadly whenever I use `new ErrorsBag()` compiler gives me `error TS2304: Cannot find name 'ErrorsBag'` while it's defined right above. When I use it without type alias (simply `new Map<string, FieldErrors>()`) it works fine.

Any hints why this is happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> whenever I use new ErrorsBag()

`type` doesn't create a *variable* it only creates a type for the type system for *type annotation purposes*. [some docs](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/types/type-system.html)

Comment: Awww, snap... So I can use it in e.g. function type signature, but internally still need to use `new Map...`, right?